# Why can't I access subclass's method using pointer of parent class?

Tags: c++

Please see my example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class base {
public:
    base() {}
    ~base() {}

    virtual void funcBase() {
        cout << "funcBase in class base" << endl;
    }
};

class derived : public base {
public:
    derived() {}
    ~derived() {}

    virtual void funcBase() {
        cout << "funcBase in class derived" << endl;
    }
    virtual void funcDerived() {} // I add virtual keyword to make sure funcDerived method is added in vtable of class
};

int main()
{
    base* obj = new derived();
    obj->funcBase(); // will print funcBase in class derived -> it's normal

    obj->funcDerived(); // error: 'class base' has no member named 'funcDerived'
    return 0;
}
```

So my question is, why can't I access the funcDerived method? I think the memory is of the derived class, so, the vpointer of class derived will point to vtable of it and this is ok!

Am I missing anything about the vtable and vpointer? What will be added to the vtable? Why is it restricted by pointer type?

Comment: This is explained in any beginner level [C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where the first step is to *"search and then research"* and you'll find plenty of SO related question for this. In particular, `obj` is a `base*` and you're trying to call `funcDerived` using `obj` while class `base` has no such method. Hence the error.

Answer (score 3):

`obj` is a pointer to `base`.
You can only call methods declared in `base` through it, even if the actual object pointed by it is a `derived`.
If these methods are polymorphic (i.e. `virtual`) the actual implementation that will be called will be that of `derived` (as you observed).

`funcDerived` is not declared in `base` and therefore cannot be accessed through a `base` pointer. The compiler issues an error because it cannot determine at **compile time** that the object is actually a `derived` one.

You can use [**`dynamic_cast`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) to cast the pointer to a `derived` one and then call `funcDerived`.
Note that `dynamic_cast` can fail at **run time** and return `nullptr` if the object pointer is not actually a pointer to `derived` (or any class derived from it):

```
derived* obj_as_derived = dynamic_cast<derived*>(obj);
if (obj_as_derived)
{
    obj_as_derived->funcDerived(); 
}
else
{
    // Handle error ...
}
```

**A side note:** better to avoid `using namespace std` - see here: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: thank you so much, The compiler issues an error because it cannot determine at compile time that the object is actually a derived one.Note that dynamic_cast can fail at run time and return nullptr if the object pointer is not actually a derived (or any class derived from it) <- I will remember it

Comment: Is there a guarantee to get a `nullptr` if the base class is not of derived type?

Comment: If you use `dynamic_cast<T*>(obj)`, you are guaranteed to get `nullptr` if `obj` is not a  `T*` (or pointer to a class derived from T).

Comment: BTW - If you do a `dynamic_cast` to a non-pointer type, you'll get an exception (std::bad_cast) instead of nullptr. But for `dynamic_cast<T*>` it will be a `nullptr`. See the dynamic_cast documentation link in my answer.

Comment: How does the C++ runtime know in the cases, when the classes have no vtable?

Comment: Ah, I see according to the doc it only works with polymorphic types to cast from base to derived. Otherwise you get a compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

```
base* obj = (something blah blah);
[...]
obj->funcDerived(); // error: 'class base' has no member named 'funcDerived'
```

The above code won't compile because the compiler (in general) has no way of guaranteeing that a `base *` pointer (like `obj`) actually points to an object of class `derived`.  For all the compiler knows, `obj` might point to a bare `base` object, or some other subclass of `base` that doesn't have a `funcDerived()` method defined; in either of those cases, trying to call a method that doesn't exist would be an error.

If you want to be able to call a virtual method via a base-class pointer, you'll need to declare that virtual method in the base class (as well as overriding it in the subclass; like what you did with `funcBase()`).  That will let the compiler know that the method will always be present for any `base` object (or subclass thereof).

Comment: "*If you want to be able to call a virtual method via a base-class pointer, you'll need to declare that virtual method in the base class*" - or, just use `dynamic_cast` to get a pointer to the derived class of the object.

Comment: Well, okay, but then you’re calling the method via a derived-class pointer.